# Geometric interpretation of dimension of a Quotient Ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $I = Q_1 \cap \cdots\cap Q_n$ be a primary decomposition of an ideal $I$ in a Noetherian ring $R$. Show that $\dim(R/I) = \max\{ \dim(R/P)$ : $P$ is an isolated prime ideal of $I \}$.

I am able to solve this problem but I want to know the geometric interpretation of this statement.

What is the geometric interpretation of this statement?

Comment: It says the dimension of $V(I)$ equals the dimension of a maximal component of it.

Comment: Ohh..I got it. Thank you.